# Parsing RSS Feed with JavaScript doesn't work for all items in RSS feed

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, rss

So this is my testing code for accessing the RSS feed. Also, [here is the RSS feed](http://ruevents.rutgers.edu/events/getEventsRss.xml?numberOfDays=7) I am trying to parse. This isn't the final design of the project, just trying to piece it together.

It works when I use the c.title,c.link parts, but **NOT** the c.description or c.pubDate part. It just says it is undefined.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>not finished yet</title>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>


          <script type='text/javascript' >/*
     /*
      * jGFeed 1.0 - Google Feed API abstraction plugin for jQuery
      *
      * Copyright (c) 2009 jQuery HowTo
      *
      * Licensed under the GPL license:
      *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
      *
      * URL:
      *   http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com
      *
      * Author URL:
      *   http://me.boo.uz
      *
      */
     (function ($) {
         $.extend({
             jGFeed: function (url, fnk, num, key) {
                 if (url == null) {
                     return false;
                 }
                 var gurl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q=" + url;
                 if (num != null) {
                     gurl += "&num=" + num;
                 }
                 if (key != null) {
                     gurl += "&key=" + key;
                 }
                 $.getJSON(gurl, function (data) {
                     if (typeof fnk == "function") {
                         fnk.call(this, data.responseData.feed);
                     } else {
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     })(jQuery);</script>




<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(window).load(function () {
        $.jGFeed('http://www.scarletknights.com/rss/rss.asp?sportid=1',
            function (feeds) {
                if (!feeds) {
                    alert('Trouble getting RSS feed :(');
                    return false;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < feeds.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = feeds.entries[i];
                    console.log(entry);
                    // Entry title
                    $('#results').append('<h1>' + entry.title + '</h1>' + '<br/>');
                }
            }, 10);

    });
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="results"></div>


    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the feed you're using has fields called `title`, `link`, `description`, and `pubDate`, you're passing that data through Google's API. You can look at the full documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#resultBasic), but the fields you want are called `title`, `link`, `contentSnippet`, and `publishedDate`.

Here's a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/LacE5/3/

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused between the feed itself and the (processed) return JSON that Google's Feed API gives you. Bear in mind that Google's Feed API doesn't return a format that's identical to the feed format.

Take a look at [the documentation for the JSON return](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/reference#resultJson) you're requesting, and you'll see the available properties for the items in the `entries` array; they include a `title` and a `link`, but not a `description` or a `pubDate`. `content` or `contentSnippet` is probably the closest you'll get to `description`; `publishedDate` will be the `pubDate` from the feed.

Google does this because their Feed API can parse more than RSS; it also parses Atom, and returns an object in a consistent format from both types of feed, to make life easier for you.

Comment: Ah thanks. Dumb mistake on my part, I assumed what it returned would be the same format. I'll have to check how the other rss feeds will end up being formatted.